# How to install Mongo DB to specific directory with user privileges in Red Hat using yumdownloader?

Tags: linux, mongodb, yum

I am trying to install Mongo DB using yumdownloader on a RED HAT server with user privileges only on a RED HAT server. I have gone through this link: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/ but it assumes I have root privileges. Also, I want to install in a specific directory.
I am not able to get a correct command to do the same.

Comment: Why do you plan to install an almost outdated version of MongoDB?

Comment: which is the newer version?

Comment: Current version is 7.0.4

Answer (score 0):

You can download the binaries from https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community as zip-file (tgz package). Then you can extract and run it in a directory of your choice.

Comment: I have extracted the files. What command I can use to install it? Is there any link to follow the installation steps?

Comment: Just run it with `mongod`. However, the defaults will not work, create a [configuration file](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.3/reference/configuration-options/) and use `mongod --config=<your config file>` or use [command line options](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.3/reference/configuration-file-settings-command-line-options-mapping/) according to your preferences.